# R fitting and forecasting daily time series

Tags: r

I am working with a daily time serie and I need to build a forecast for 90 days (or maybe more) based on my history - The current time serie has roughly 298 data points.

The issue I have is the famous flat line in the final forecast - and yes I might not have a seasonality but I am trying to work this out.  Another issue is how to find the best model and adapt it from here on for this kind of behaviour.

I created a test case to investigate this further and any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

To start with

```
x <- day_data  # My time serie
z <- 90        # Days to forecast

low_bound_date <- as.POSIXlt(min(x$time), format = "%m/%d/%Y") # oldest date in the DF.

> low_bound_date
[1] "2015-12-21 PST"

low_bound_date$yday 
> low_bound_date$yday  # Day in Julian
[1] 354

lbyear <- as.numeric(substr(low_bound_date, 1, 4))
> lbyear
[1] 2015
```

This is my time serie content

```
> ts
Time Series:
Start = c(2065, 4) 
End = c(2107, 7) 
Frequency = 7 
  [2] 20.73 26.19 27.51 26.11 26.28 27.58 26.84 27.00 26.30 28.75 28.43 39.03 41.36 45.42 44.80 45.33 47.79 44.70 45.17
 [20] 34.90 32.54 32.75 33.35 34.76 34.11 33.59 33.60 38.08 30.45 29.66 31.09 31.36 31.96 29.30 30.04 30.85 31.13 25.09
 [39] 17.88 23.73 25.31 31.30 35.18 34.13 34.96 35.12 27.36 38.33 38.59 38.14 38.54 41.72 37.15 35.92 37.37 32.39 30.64
 [58] 30.57 30.66 31.16 31.50 30.68 32.21 32.27 32.55 33.61 34.80 33.53 33.09 20.90  6.91  7.82 15.78  7.25  6.19  6.38
 [77] 38.06 39.82 35.53 38.63 41.91 39.76 37.26 38.79 37.74 35.61 39.70 35.79 35.36 29.63 22.07 35.39 35.99 37.35 38.82
 [96] 25.80 21.31 18.85  9.52 20.75 36.83 44.12 37.79 34.45 36.05 16.39 21.84 31.39 34.26 31.50 30.87 28.88 42.83 41.52
[115] 42.34 47.35 44.47 44.10 44.49 26.89 18.17 40.44 43.93 41.56 39.98 40.31 40.59 40.17 40.22 40.50 32.68 35.89 36.06
[134] 34.30 22.67 12.56 13.29 12.34 28.00 35.27 36.57 33.78 32.15 33.58 34.62 30.96 32.06 33.05 30.66 32.47 30.42 32.83
[153] 31.74 29.39 22.39 12.58 16.46  5.36  4.01 15.32 32.79 31.66 32.02 27.60 31.47 31.61 34.96 27.77 31.91 33.94 33.43
[172] 26.94 28.38 21.42 24.51 23.82 31.71 26.64 27.96 29.29 29.25 28.70 27.02 27.62 30.90 27.46 27.37 26.46 27.77 13.61
[191]  5.87 12.18  5.68  4.15  4.35  4.42 16.42 25.18 26.06 27.39 27.57 28.86 15.18  5.19  5.61  8.28  7.78  5.13  4.90
[210]  5.02  5.27 16.31 25.01 26.19 25.96 24.93 25.53 25.56 26.39 26.80 26.73 26.00 25.61 25.90 25.89 13.80  6.66  6.41
[229]  5.28  5.64  5.71  5.38  5.76  7.20  7.27  5.55  5.31  5.94  5.75  5.93  5.77  6.57  5.52  5.51  5.47  5.69 19.75
[248] 29.22 30.75 29.63 30.49 29.48 31.83 30.42 29.27 30.40 29.91 32.00 30.09 28.93 14.54  7.75  5.63 17.17 22.27 24.93
[267] 35.94 37.42 33.13 25.88 24.27 37.64 37.42 38.33 35.20 21.32  7.32  4.81  5.17 17.49 23.77 23.36 27.60 26.53 24.99
[286] 24.22 23.76 24.10 24.22 27.06 25.53 23.40 37.07 26.52 25.19 28.02 28.53 26.67
```

First step, I get my data in `ts`

```
day_data_ts <- ts(x$avg_day, start = c(lbyear,low_bound_date$yday), frequency=7)

plot(day_data_ts)
```

[plot_ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTPmg.png)

```
acf(day_data_ts)
```

[acf_ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl8ve.png)

Second step, I get my data in `msts`

```
day_data_msts <- msts(x$avg_day, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25), start = c(lbyear,low_bound_date$yday))

plot(day_data_msts)

acf(day_data_msts)
```

I did several fitting iterations to try and figure out the best fit and forecast model.

First fitting test is with the `ts` only.

```
fit1 <- HoltWinters(day_data_ts)
> fit1
    Holt-Winters exponential smoothing with trend and additive seasonal component.
    Call: HoltWinters(x = day_data_ts)
    Smoothing parameters: alpha: 1   beta : 0.006757112  gamma: 0

    Coefficients:
             [,1]
    a  28.0922449
    b   0.1652477
    s1  0.6241837
    s2  1.9084694
    s3  0.9913265
    s4  0.8198980
    s5 -1.7015306
    s6 -1.2201020
    s7 -1.4222449


fit2 <- tbats(day_data_ts)
> fit2
    BATS(1, {0,0}, 0.8, -)
    Parameters:   Alpha: 1.309966     Beta: -0.3011143    Damping Parameter: 0.800001
    Seed States:
              [,1]
    [1,] 15.282259
    [2,]  2.177787
    Sigma: 5.501356     AIC: 2723.911


fit3 <- ets(day_data_ts)
> fit3
    ETS(A,N,N) 
      Smoothing parameters: alpha = 0.9999 
      Initial states:       l = 25.2275 
      sigma:  5.8506
         AIC     AICc      BIC 
    2756.597 2756.678 2767.688 


fit4 <- auto.arima(day_data_ts)
> fit4
    ARIMA(1,1,2)                    
    Coefficients:
             ar1      ma1      ma2
          0.7396  -0.6897  -0.2769
    s.e.  0.0545   0.0690   0.0621
    sigma^2 estimated as 30.47:  log likelihood=-927.9
    AIC=1863.81   AICc=1863.94   BIC=1878.58
```

Second test is using `msts`.  I also changed the `ets` model to `MAM`.

```
fit5 <- tbats(day_data_msts)
> fit5
    BATS(1, {0,0}, 0.8, -)
    Parameters:   Alpha: 1.309966     Beta: -0.3011143    Damping Parameter: 0.800001
    Seed States:
              [,1]
    [1,] 15.282259
    [2,]  2.177787
    Sigma: 5.501356     AIC: 2723.911


fit6 <- ets(day_data_msts, model="MAN")
> fit6
    ETS(M,A,N) 
      Smoothing parameters:     alpha = 0.9999      beta  = 9e-04 
      Initial states:           l = 52.8658         b = 3.9184 
      sigma:  0.3459
         AIC     AICc      BIC 
    3042.744 3042.949 3061.229 


fit7 <- auto.arima(day_data_msts)
> fit7
    ARIMA(1,1,2)                    
    Coefficients:
             ar1      ma1      ma2
          0.7396  -0.6897  -0.2769
    s.e.  0.0545   0.0690   0.0621
    sigma^2 estimated as 30.47:  log likelihood=-927.9
    AIC=1863.81   AICc=1863.94   BIC=1878.58
```

Comment: I am trying to eliminate the flat line by chosing the best forecastign model.

Comment: If your goal is to choose the model that you expect to give you the most accurate predictions, I would: partition your data into training and test sets; estimate your various models from the training set; use those models to generate predictions over the test set; compare the accuracy of those predictions using an appropriate statistic (e.g., MASE); and, finally, use the winning model to generate forecasts for the next 90 days. Or try https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecastHybrid/forecastHybrid.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can forecast on previously estimated model as follows (use built in timeseries `LakeHuron`):

```
library(forecast)
y <- LakeHuron
tsdisplay(y)
# estimate ARMA(1,1)
mod_2 <- Arima(y, order = c(1, 0, 1))
#make forecast for 5 periods (years in this case)
fHuron <- forecast(mod_2, h = 5)
#show results in table
fHuron
#plot results
plot(fHuron)
```

This will give you:
[image]
Pay attention that ARIMA model bases its forecast on previous values, so if we make prediction on many periods the model will use already predicted values to predict next. Which will reduce accuracy.

To fit optimal ARIMA model use this function:

```
library(R.utils) #for the function 'withTimeout'
fitARIMA<-function(timeseriesObject, timout)
{
    final.aic <- Inf
    final.order <- c(0,0,0)
    for (p in 0:5) for (q in 0:5) {
        if ( p == 0 && q == 0) {
        next
        }

        arimaFit = tryCatch( 
        withTimeout(arima(timeseriesObject
                            ,order=c(p, 0, q))
                    ,timeout = timeout)
        ,error=function( err ) FALSE
        ,warning=function( err ) FALSE )

        if( !is.logical( arimaFit ) ) {
        current.aic <- AIC(arimaFit)
        if (current.aic < final.aic) {
            final.aic <- current.aic
            final.order <- c(p, 0, q)
            final.arima <- arima(timeseriesObject, order=final.order)
        }
        } else {
        next
        }
    }
    final.order<-c(final.order,final.aic)
    final.order
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, are you recommending to use ARIMA then for daily forecasting? I tried it now and I am still getting a flat line.              ARIMA(1,0,1) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1  intercept
      0.7966  0.2621    26.6071
s.e.  0.0394  0.0632     1.9492

sigma^2 estimated as 30.53:  log likelihood=-931.43
AIC=1870.87   AICc=1871   BIC=1885.65

Comment: ARIMA is usually used for one period forecasting, because you can get additional info when this period comes. This model will give you flat line in most cases. The direction (up or down) is more important. If your data have seasonality you can estimate and add it separately to ARIMA forecast.  Notice also, that ARIMA(1,0,1) model was applied to my example data, not yours. In your case optimal p and q in ARIMA may be different.